# How do I reference a var.yaml externally in devops

Tags: variables, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a unit test repo which works fine when I execute. Now, I wish to call the unit test from from an external repo where the deployment happens.

I am able to reference the unit test from the external repo but this repo (unit test) also has a variable.yaml file. I am not able to make it read this file

***Unit test repo : Main.yaml file***

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: "Set Python Version"
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "$(PYTHON_VERSION)"
```

***Deployment repo:***

```
trigger:
  - none

variables: 
  - template: pipelines/cd/vars.yaml@external_repo

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: external_repo
      type: git
      name: <Projectname>/<reponame>
      ref: Automation
 
stages:
  - stage: 
    pool:
      vmImage: "windows-latest"
    displayName: test automation

    jobs:
      - job: RunExternalPipeline
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            persistCredentials: true
            path: self
          - checkout: external_repo
            persistCredentials: true
            path: external_repo
          - template: pipelines/cd/main.yaml@external_repo
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to make it read this file"? Do you get an error? What is the behavior you're observing?

Comment: I get his error from Main.yaml

`##[error]Invalid file path 'D:\a\1\s'.
Finishing: Set Python Version`

Comment: That's not a problem with loading the variables. At worst, it's a problem with scoping and variable resolution. Try adding the `variables` block to your job definition.